# Some keys when pressed insert two characters

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a Dell Inspiron 1545 runnning Windows Vista.

For a while, the keys "t", "y", "[", "]", "5", "6", F7, F8, F9, and backspace refused to respond most of time. I reconnected the keyboard wires, and they now respond. However, when I press one of those keys, it inserts two keys at once. For example, "t5", "y6" backspace and F9, F8 and F7.

Any idea how to fix this? Also, there are moments where this seems to repair itself, but returns eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you didn't insert the [keyboard cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable) correctly. A misaligned connector like this may explain the double key responses, because each pin will connect with two adjacent wires.

Try reseating the cable and make sure that the lock mechanism doesn't cause any displacement.